# Typing Array of objects with React.ComponentType and props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have scenario, where I need to have Array with React Components and their props.
I am trying to create array of objects for Component1 and Component2 as below:

```
const Component1 = (props: Component1Props) => {/** */};
const Component2 = (props: Component2Props) => {/** */};

const componentsArray = [{ Component: Component1, props: {} as React.ComponentProps<typeof Component1> }, { Component: Component2, props: {} as React.ComponentProps<typeof Component2> }];
```

Is there way to type componentsArray to avoid explicitly typing props object for each array entry so later I could use componentsArray as this:

```
componentsArray.map(({Component, props}, index) => <Component key={index} {...props} />)
```

I could use something like:

```
type ComponentWithProps<T> = {
   Component: React.ComponentType<T>;
   props: T;
}
```

But can't think of solution how to type array of those types as there is generic T present.